# What is the best way to handle a button when a `TimePicker` component is invalid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What is the best way to handle a button when a `TimePicker` component is invalid?

```
import * as React from "react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { TimePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker";
import { DesktopDatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date());
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    console.log(newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
    setError(false);
  };

  const handleError = () => {
    setError(true);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <Stack spacing={3}>
        <DesktopDatePicker
          label="Date desktop"
          inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
        <TimePicker
          label="Time"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onError={handleError}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />

        <Button variant="contained" disabled={error}>
          Contained
        </Button>
      </Stack>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Right now, even if the `TimePicker` or `DesktopDatePicker` has an error (for example, change the time manually), you can hit the `Save` button.

But I'd like the button to be disabled if `TimePicker` or `DesktopDatePicker` are invalid.

How can I do it?

I tried using `onError` so when onError is fired, change the `error` state to `true`, but there isn't a good way to set the `error` state to `false` once the error is gone.

Comment: I always do a date checking using date-fns parser in the onChange event, if that helps u.

Answer (score 0):

Having `value == "Invalid Date"`, if true, displays an error message. if not save an event in `saveEvent` function.

This is the way I found so far.

```
export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date());

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    console.log(newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const saveEvent = () => {
    if (value == "Invalid Date") {
      console.log("Show error message");
    } else {
      // function to save event
    }
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <Stack spacing={3}>
        <DesktopDatePicker
          label="Date desktop"
          inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
        <TimePicker
          label="Time"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />

        <Button variant="contained" onClick={saveEvent}>
          Contained
        </Button>
      </Stack>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```